# How Dynamically generate pdf using fpdf and google graph in php

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to generate pdf using fpdf library so that I can download dynamic pdf from php page

Comment: Nice idea. Then what is next? What you want?

Comment: See dompdf (https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/). It generates a PDF from an HTML page, it's great... :-)